# Redirects Aren't Being Followed

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

I've setup my `.htaccess` file to redirect certain media (images) to other images. But the redirection is not occurring (the old media is still accessible).

What is wrong with my `.htaccess` file redirects? It's not due to spaces in the urls or etc. (there aren't any). Any ideas?

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch  (?i)^/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/emailImg1.jpg http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg11.png
RedirectMatch  (?i)^/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/emailImg2.jpg http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg21.png
RedirectMatch  (?i)^/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/emailImg3.jpg http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg31.png
RedirectMatch  (?i)^/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg4.jpg http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg41.png
RedirectMatch  (?i)^/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg1.png http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg11.png
RedirectMatch  (?i)^/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg2.png http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg21.png
RedirectMatch  (?i)^/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg3.png http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg31.png
RedirectMatch  (?i)^/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg4.png http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg41.png

... Wordpress rules below
```

Comment: I haven't done much with redirects, but am wondering if it needs a 301 added. ie `RedirectMatch 301 (?i)^/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/emailImg1.jpg http://www.soribo.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/emailImg11.png`

See: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch.html

Comment: @user3633383 Thanks for the advice but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: @down-voter what is the reason for the down vote?

Comment: What is the `(?i)` for?

Comment: RTMF => http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Are there any rules above `RedirectMatch` lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-content/uploads/

RewriteRule ^2015/04/(emailImg1\.jpg)$ 2015/05/$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^2015/04/(emailImg2\.jpg)$ 2015/05/$1 [L,NC,R]

# rest of the rules using same pattern
```